# Access Refresh All in VBA - Update table while it is open

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am working with an Access database and I have a table linked to a form. Currently, I can see the change in the table if I close it and reopen it or press the Refresh All on the ribbon menu. I want to be able to add entry in the form and see any update in that table while the table is open. Is there a VBA code for Refresh All that I can use in a button? There is a video on Youtube that shows what I want to do but it does not explain how it is done. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lPxQmnI37SE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call these commands in the *AfterUpdate* event of the form:

```
DoCmd.SelectObject acTable, "YourTable"
DoCmd.Requery
DoCmd.GoToRecord acDataTable, "YourTable", acLast
```

Comment: Thanks Gustav, I added the commands to a button and it worked fine!